# SwiftUI not updating with Bluetooth events that change object variables

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-bluetooth

I’m playing around with some Bluetooth objects and having issues getting SwiftUI to update the view.

Essentially I have a CBCentralManagerDelegate object (btManager) that has a published array of CBPeripheralDelegate objects (btPeripheral) that store their state in variables that get updated when the subscribed Bluetooth messages get processed. However the SwiftUI display (a row in a List) doesn’t update immediately but usually when something else happens to trigger an update (e.g. a different button press).

Im guessing it’s to do with the asynchronous way the peripheral’s delegate methods get called, but despite both classes being ObservableObjects and the array in the manager being @Published it doesn’t update the display straight away.

Any tips would be welcome!

Difficult to show all the code, but the gist of it is:

```
class BTDataManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    @Published var peripherals: [BTPeripheral] = []
    private var centralManager: CBCentralManager!

    // CBCentralManagerDelegate methods
}


class BTPeripheral: NSObject, ObservableObject, Identifiable, CBPeripheralDelegate {
    var manager: BTDataManager?
    var peripheral: CBPeripheral?
    var RSSI: Int?
    var data = "Test"
    var id = UUID()

    // CBPeripheralDelegate methods
}
```

So for example when a peripheral delegate method is called and the data `var` is updated, the SwiftUI view doesn't immediately update.

My ListView is:

```
struct PeripheralList: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var modelData: BTDataManager

    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach (modelData.peripherals){ peripheral in
                PeripheralDetailRow(peripheral: peripheral)
                    .environmentObject(modelData)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PeripheralDetailRow: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var modelData: BTDataManager
    var peripheral: BTPeripheral
    var index: Int {
        modelData.peripherals.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == peripheral.id })!
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(peripheral.id.uuidString.suffix(5))
            Text(modelData.peripherals[index].data)
                .font(caption)
    }
}
```

When a peripheral's delegate function is fired and updates the `data` var, then the view doesn't update until something else triggers a refresh.

Comment: You need to show your code, but I'm guessing that you have an `@Published` array of objects.  The publisher will only fire when the array itself is modified (eg. an element is added or removed), not when a property of an element changes.  You need each element to also be an `ObservableObject`

Comment: Thank you, as per the code I've added above the objects in the array are set as ObservableObject but I'm stil not seeing instant updates.

Comment: Just passing by. Is your published object modified on the main queue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after typing this out I think I have solved it.

`var data` becomes `@Published var data`

In the DetailRow, I have `@EnvironmentObject var peripheral: BTPeripheral` and I don't need the modelData or index stuff.
In the List View I use `.environmentObject(peripheral)` to pass it through.

Seems to work now, although I'm not 100% that this is the correct way.